# IntelliJ hint while rounding BigDecimal division stream result

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-stream, bigdecimal

I have a little bit strange problem with IntelliJ hint while dividing result at the end of stream operation.

```
products.stream()
        .filter(
            order ->
                order.getEstimatedRealizationDate().compareTo(begin) > 0
                    && order.getEstimatedRealizationDate().compareTo(end) < 0)
        .map(order -> order.getProduct().getPrice())
        .reduce(ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
        .divide(valueOf(productList.size()))
        .setScale(3, RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

Regardless of how you set the rounding, IntelliJ constantly claims that the dividing operation may carry a risk in the form of ArtithmeticException in the form of a message and backlighting divide operation. I was using either round() option.

> Reports calls to divide() or setScale() without a rounding mode
>   argument. Such calls can lead to an ArithmeticException when the exact
>   value cannot be represented in the result (e.g. because it has a
>   non-terminating decimal expansion). Specifying a rounding mode
>   prevents the ArithmeticException.

I have the impression that I've tried every possible variant, but still, IntelliJ doesn't give up. Please suggest what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for each kind of help.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Doing a static import of `valueOf` is a bad idea, because so very many classes has a method by that name, so it's unclear what type of value you end up with. In this context we can assume it's `BigDecimal`, since that's what `divide` requires, but I think you made the code less readable by doing the static import. --- Now, doing static import of `CEILING` would be a good candidate, because you don't really lose any information by hiding the `RoundingMode` name.

Comment: The variant you're looking for is to tell the `divide` method to do the rounding: `.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(productList.size()), 3, CEILING)`

Comment: Indeed, the current solution strongly blurs readability and can introduce unnecessary problems. Thank you very much for your good suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setScale` just returns a `BigDecimal` object with the specified scale. You want to use the overloaded [`divide`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal,%20int,%20java.math.RoundingMode)) method

`divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)`:

```
products.stream()
        .filter(
            order ->
                order.getEstimatedRealizationDate().compareTo(begin) > 0
                    && order.getEstimatedRealizationDate().compareTo(end) < 0)
        .map(order -> order.getProduct().getPrice())
        .reduce(ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
        .divide(valueOf(productList.size()), 3, RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

In this example I am using `RoundingMode.CEILING` but here are the docs for [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) in case you want to use a different rounding mode.

Comment: Use `divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, int roundingMode)`, not `divide(BigDecimal divisor, int roundingMode)` and `setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode)` combination, because you'd want the rounding to occur at the desired scale (3). Rounding to the scale of whatever value `getPrice()` happens to return is arbitrary, and likely less that the desired scale of `3`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the immediate help of the dear community. I completely failed to understand the assumption of setting the rounding option, until then.